# optimizing inserts using core data

Tags: core-data

I have to insert large amount of data say around 2000 records into sqlite database using core data. It takes 1 minute 30 sec after using caching and batch processing. Still I want to improve the insert time. Is there any way in core data to avoid this UI block up while insertion of large data.

Answer (score 0):

Chaithanya,

A standard solution to your problem is to insert the items on a background queue. You should read the relevant sections of the CD programming guide for examples.

Andrew

Comment: Hi adonoho,Db write is already in background thread. After analyzing my db design, I implemented caching for one of the table and it considerably reduced the insert time.